# Sum of x raised to odd powers till infinity where x is less than 0

Tags: summation, power-series

I have an geometric series which has the following form

`0.5^3 + 0.5^5 + 0.5^7 + 0.5^9 .... 0.5^inf`

Is there a formula to find the sum of this series ?

Comment: There's no $x$ in your expression (which is not an equation)

Comment: Changed wording.

Comment: This is a geometric series with common ratio $r=0.5^2$ and first term $a=0.5^3$. It evaluates to $\frac a{1-r}$

Comment: Look [here](https://www.cuemath.com/progression/sum-of-an-infinite-gp/) for a proof.

Comment: The $x$ remains a mystery.

Comment: Oh, I see your point. Fixed it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple geometric progression $\{a_n\}$, its general term is given by $a_n=a_1q^{n-1}$ , correspondingly, summation formula is $S_n=a_1\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$. Specifically, when $\vert q\vert<1$, take limitation on both sides, one obtains $S_{\infty}=\frac{a_1}{1-q}$.

So when it comes to your problem, $a_1=0.5^3, q=0.5^2, S_{n}=0.5^3\times\frac{1-0.5^{2n}}{1-0.5^2}, S_{\infty}=\frac{0.5^3}{1-0.5^2}=\frac{1}{6}$ .